# Extra Spacing at Top of <div>

Tags: html, margin, padding

Can't figure out why there is extra spacing. Spent quite a bit of time on trying to figure out CSS styling but no luck. How can I get 'BBC' vertically centered to the line next to it (i.e, in the middle of the box not the center)

Also if you uncomment line 10 in the fiddle, it behaves completely differently. can you explain why it does so?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/childishgovindo/vLzdpt07/2)

```
<div class="container top-nav-bar">

    <div class="top-nav-logo-area">
        <span class="logo">B</span>
        <span class="logo">B</span>
        <span class="logo">C</span>
    </div>

    <div class="top-nav-link-div">
    <!--<a class="black-nav-links" href="#">Sign in</a>-->

    </div>


      html,body,p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

   .container {
        width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .top-nav-bar {
        height: 40px;
    }

    .top-nav-logo-area {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .logo {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        font-family: monospace;
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    .top-nav-link-div {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        border-left: 1px grey solid;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: black;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For all of your requirements, I recommend removing your "height" setting in the nav bar. You need to add and adjust margins and paddings to get the logo evenly placed, and you also need to use "position: relative;" on both the container and the "sign in" div to get placement exactly in the vertical middle.

Here is a jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/deborah/t8oyLprs/1/

Here is the CSS. If you are building an entire website and trying to customize Bootstrap, you will benefit from doing a Google search for CSS tutorials and going through them.

```
   html,body,p {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
   }

   .container {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .top-nav-bar {
        /* remove the height and let the margins/paddings on the child divs set it */
        border-bottom: 1px #cccccc solid;
    }

    .top-nav-logo-area {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative; /* makes this container accept positions for the child div */
        margin: 10px; /* equal margin around the logo centers it vertically */
        padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px; /* padding top and bottom centers the border */
        border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;
    }

    .top-nav-logo-area:after {
      content: '';
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .logo {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        font-family: monospace;
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    .top-nav-link-div {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        border-left: 1px grey solid;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: black;
        position: relative; /* necessary for positioning */
          top: -5px; /* the position adjustment */

    }
```

Your commented line contains the "sign in" text, which is using CSS for the area also. That is why the layout changes when you comment it out. Putting HTML in a comment tells the browser, "ignore this."

Comment: Hi Deborah, I apologize I know its not centered, but my motive with the question was why is it not in the middle of the div. I have rephrased my question. Sorry about that!

Comment: do you mean in the center of the html?

Comment: which middle, vertical or horizontal, in which div? Do you mean, why is it at the left instead of the center of the page?

Comment: thanks for that! I am still having issues. I add relative position and push it down. Nothing Changes. Then as soon as I enter text in .top-nav-div-link div everything gets unaligned and BBC jumps to the top. If I fix the BBC using your recommendations, then the  .top-nav-link-div div as it falls below... http://jsfiddle.net/childishgovindo/vLzdpt07/4/

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear, I want things to be vertically in the middle of my 40px nav bar and I want a border between the bbc and signup. For whatever reason I am not able to do this.

Comment: you have to add "position: relative;" to the container div AND to the div you want to push up or down. The container's position: relative makes it possible to push things around in it. The div you are trying to push must also have position: relative (and the top + left values) to tell it, "your position will be relative to the parent, according to these values". For border, just add border-right: 1px sold #ccc; to your top-nav-bar-logo-area div.

Comment: I understand Deborah, however even after changing to your code, it does not work. Either the BBC logo jumps up or down based on if I have text in .top-nav-link-div. Could you link me to a js fiddle? One of the other problems I encounter is that the border does not go 100% down to the border. See here with your changes:  http://jsfiddle.net/childishgovindo/vLzdpt07/5/ Thanks a ton for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

try these changes in jsfiddle

```
.top-nav-bar {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    height: 35px;
}
.top-nav-logo-area {
    display: block;
    margin: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For centering the divs in their container horizontally on the page do this.

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```